# Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlInterop.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I'm running VisualStudio 2013 Ultimate (with Blend) on 2 separate machines (different vendors) and have the same issue.

When I double click on to the MainPage.Xaml when creating new windows store app or phone app the designer does not open.

I receive the following error:

> System.DllNotFoundException Unable to load DLL
>   'Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlInterop.dll': The specified module
>   could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E

This occurs on VS update 2, 3 & 4 RC. I have tried repairing VS and the .net framework. I've tried installing 4.5.2. I have deleted the contents in the ShadowCache directory but still no cigar.

This issue is driving me crazy. This didn't happen prior to VS update 2...which I need for some XAML development.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks

Comment: Please format your question in the future. You have bold, underline, code sample, etc buttons. Please use them. You can have your error between `` marks in this case, for example. It's easier for the ones who read your question.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709939/microsoft-expression-windowsxamlinterop-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-fo. I would mark it as a duplicate but the original question lacks an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlInterop.dll'

That DLL belongs in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend directory, make sure it is there.  It is a mixed-mode assembly, containing native code which depends on other unmanaged DLLs, which is what the error code suggests is the problem.  It cannot be loaded because one of the dependent DLLs cannot be found.

First and foremost are `d3d9.dll` and `d3d11.dll`, DirectX dependencies for respectively DX9 and DX11 that belong in your c:\windows\syswow64 directory. They in turn have a bunch of dependencies themselves. Surely the underlying cause of the problem, the DirectX runtime gets messed with too much by game installers and whatnot.  If necessary, narrow it down by enabling loader snaps or by using SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see it searching for the DLL and not finding it.  If you need help repairing your DX install then ask questions at superuser.com

Comment: The DLL files are present in the Blend directory. I tried running fixes for DirectX and everything reports well on that front. When running procmon it did report the absence of **Windows.VisualStudio.Design*.dll**. I will continue to troubleshoot and post back. Thanks

Comment: Microsoft have confirmed this is a bug. Fix will be released in update 4 (not RC) this month.

Comment: Hi,


Finally fixed.

The file in **c:\windows\sysWOW64\mcvcr120.dll** needs the correct permissions (I chose Full control) applied for the ALL APPLICATIONS PACKAGES group.

I am in the process of finding out where in the installation process the correct permissions are not being applied.




Cheers

Tyler

Comment: sorry typo. the file name is **msvcr120.dll**